# Custom URL for REST API in Nodejs + mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

So I have the following mongoose schema in the nodejs api:

```
var profileschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:           { type: String },
    surname:        { type: String },
    id:             { type: String }
});
```

---

And the following route:

```
 var profile = express.Router();

 profile.route('/profile')
      .get(profilecrtl.findAllProfile)
      .post(profilecrtl.addProfile);
```

---

I can make another routes like **/profile/:id** and they work perfectly.

But I would like to generate custom URLs depending on what parameters the users asks and wants on the same method without having to code each case. For example:

- **/profile?id=1234** should give me the full info about the id=1234 profile

---

```
{ 
  id: '1234',
  name: 'john'
  surname: 'wicked'
}
```

---

- **/profile?id=1234&name=john** should give me the same full profile as before

---

```
{ 
  id: '1234',
  name: 'john'
  surname: 'wicked'
}
```

---

- **/profile?id=1234&fields=name** should give me just the name of the id=1234 profile

---

```
{ 
  name: 'john'
}
```

---

Is there any robust way to do this in the **same case** so it can easily scale if there is any change in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Express, you should use `req.query` to get an object with the requested arguments.

```
profile.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    //Depending on what the query contains, find stuff in your DB with mongoose!
});
```

`req.query` is a JSON object containing all of the query arguments of the request, so a request like

**/profile?id=1234&fields=name**

would result in a JSON object like

```
{ 
  id: '1234',
  fields: 'name'
}
```

from which you can create your database queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added some examples. I understand how req.query works, but I'd like to do it as much general as possible taking into account that the get request could be very dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel tho he doesn't answer your full question.
here's an example how to do what you're looking for you'll have to do the mongoose queries yourself tho.

```
 profile.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
      if(query.id&& !query.field)
       {
          //the user is asking for the full profile
       }else if(query.field)
       {
          switch(query.field)
          {
            case "name":
             //the user is asking for the field name
            break;
          }
       }else{
        }
});
```